# Design pattern for dynamic C# object

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a queue that processes objects in a while loop. They are added asynchronously somewhere.. like this:

```
myqueue.pushback(String value);
```

And they are processed like this:

```
while(true)
{
    String path =  queue.pop();
    if(process(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Good!");
    }
    else
    {
        queue.pushback(path);
    }
}
```

Now, the thing is that I'd like to modify this to support a TTL-like (time to live) flag, so the file path would be added o more than n times.

**How could I do this, while keeping the `bool process(String path)` function signature?** I don't want to modify that.

I thought about holding a map, or a list that counts how many times the process function returned false for a path and drop the path from the list at the n-th return of false. I wonder how can this be done more dynamically, and preferably I'd like the TTL to automatically decrement itself at each new addition to the process. I hope I am not talking trash. 
Maybe using something like this

```
class JobData
{
   public string path;
   public short ttl;

   public  static implicit operator String(JobData jobData) {jobData.ttl--; return jobData.path;}
}
```

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your `JobData` approach?

Comment: Well the thing is that I Don t want to modify the process function, I just want 'JobData' object that is able to do an implicit conversion to String in c# and some ideas about dynamically and implicitly decrement the tll value

Comment: A possible additional solution which I'll mention but not endorse is to add an extension method to the String type with your TTL counter. Not ideal or recommended because it adds a meaningless method to string everywhere (even limited to a very local namespace), but it would solve your specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the idea of a JobData class, but there's already an answer demonstrating that, and the fact that you're working with file paths give you another possible advantage. Certain characters are not valid in file paths, and so you could choose one to use as a delimiter. The advantage here is that the queue type remains a string, and so you would not have to modify any of your existing asynchronous code. You can see a list of reserved path characters here:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words

For our purposes, I'll use the percent (%) character. Then you can modify your code as follows, and nothing else needs to change:

```
const int startingTTL = 100;
const string delimiter = "%";

while(true)
{
    String[] path =  queue.pop().Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());
    int ttl = path.Length > 1?--int.Parse(path[1]):startingTTL;

    if(process(path[0]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Good!");
    }
    else if (ttl > 0)
    {
        queue.pushback(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", path[0], delimiter,ttl));             
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TTL expired for path: {0}" path[0]);
    }
}
```

Again, from a pure architecture standpoint, a class with two properties is a better design... but from a practical standpoint, [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it): this option means you can avoid going back and changing other asynchronous code that pushes into the queue. That code still only needs to know about the strings, and will work with this unmodified.

One more thing. I want to point out that this is a fairly tight loop, prone to running away with a cpu core. Additionally, if this is the .Net queue type and your tight loop gets ahead of your asynchronous produces to empty the queue, you'll throw an exception, which would break out of the while(true) block. You can solve both issues with code like this:

```
while(true)
{

    try 
    {
        String[] path =  queue.pop().Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());
        int ttl = path.Length > 1?--int.Parse(path[1]):startingTTL;

        if(process(path[0]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Good!");
        }
        else if (ttl > 0)
        {
            queue.pushback(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", path[0], delimiter,ttl));             
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TTL expired for path: {0}" path[0]);
        }
    }
    catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        //Queue.Dequeue throws InvalidOperation if the queue is empty... sleep for a bit before trying again
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the constraint is that `bool process(String path)` cannot be touched/changed then put the functionality into `myqueue`.  You can keep its public signatures of `void pushback(string path)` and `string pop()`, but internally you can track your TTL.  You can either wrap the string paths in a  `JobData`-like class that gets added to the internal queue, or you can have a secondary `Dictionary` keyed by path.  Perhaps even something as simple as saving the last `pop`ed path and if the subsequent `push` is the same path you can assume it was a rejected/failed item.  Also, in your `pop` method you can even discard a path that has been rejected too many time and internally fetch the next path so the calling code is blissfully unaware of the issue.

Comment: Given the asynchronous nature of the pushing code, matching a push with the last pop seems like a very bad idea.

Comment: Yes that's true.  Probably best to stick with a wrapping data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could abstract/encapsulate the functionality of the "job manager". Hide the queue and implementation from the caller so you can do whatever you want without the callers caring. Something like this:

```
public static class JobManager
{
    private static Queue<JobData> _queue;

    static JobManager() { Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { StartProcessing(); }); }

    public static void AddJob(string value)
    {
        //TODO: validate

        _queue.Enqueue(new JobData(value));
    }

    private static StartProcessing()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_queue.Count > 0)
            {
                JobData data = _queue.Dequeue();
                if (!process(data.Path))
                {
                    data.TTL--;
                    if (data.TTL > 0)
                        _queue.Enqueue(data);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

    private class JobData
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public short TTL { get; set; }

        public JobData(string value)
        {
            this.Path = value;
            this.TTL = DEFAULT_TTL;
        }
    }

}
```

Then your processing loop can handle the TTL value.

Edit - Added a simple processing loop. This code isn't thread safe, but should hopefully give you an idea.

Comment: The original question says "How could I do this, while keeping the bool process(String path) function signature?". I'm not sure I see where the `process(String path)` fits in with your code...

Comment: That would still be within the processing loop

Comment: Using `Thread.Sleep()` like this is a bad idea. Having a `static` constructor that never returns is an *extremely* bad idea.

Comment: @svick Good point... better? Also, what would you do instead of the thread sleep? A timer maybe?

Comment: @JasonP Somewhat. But I don't think it makes sense for this to be a `static` class. And that starting it is invisible with no way of stopping it.

Comment: @JasonP I would probably use `Monitor.Wait()` and `Monitor.Pulse()`. Or even better, `BlockingCollection<T>`.

Comment: @svick It's certainly not production-ready. It was just intended to show how the encapsulation could work to add functionality "behind the scenes."